# Mongoid Production Issue: Failed to connect to a master node

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, passenger, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've switched away from Mongo_Mapper to Mongoid and am having trouble deploying to production, for some reason.  I'm using NGINX, Rails 3.1, and Passenger.  I keep getting this message, "Failed to connect to a master node at myusernamehere:27017 (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)".

```
  defaults: &defaults
  host: localhost
  # slaves:
  #   - host: slave1.local
  #     port: 27018
  #   - host: slave2.local
  #     port: 27019

  development:
    <<: *defaults
    database: s3uploadergen_development

  test:
    <<: *defaults
    database: s3uploadergen_test

  production:
    host: localhost
    port: 27017
    database: mydbnamehere
    username: myuserhere
    password: mypasswordhere
```

I've triple-checked all settings and tried the ENV approach as well (adding the ENV variables to production.rb and calling them via the documented mongoid approach but had the same issue):

```
production:
  host: <%= ENV['MONGOID_HOST'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PORT'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['MONGOID_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['MONGOID_DATABASE'] %>
```

Ideally, I want to just specify it either in production.rb or an initializer of some sort.

Comment: I'm assuming that by "documented mongoid approach" you mean setting the recommended "uri" param instead of all those different setttings?

Comment: No, I thought that was for Heroku only, which I'm not using.  Can you post a link? Or better yet, an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that by "documented mongoid approach" you mean setting the recommended "uri" param instead of all those different setttings. You might want to try it since it's the recommended way of doing it.

```
defaults: &defaults
  persist_in_safe_mode: true

development:
  <<: *defaults
  host: localhost
  database: app_development

test:
  <<: *defaults
  host: localhost
  database: app_test

production:
  <<: *defaults
  uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
```

Note that I do use Heroku but I don't use the MongoHQ add on. I just use it directly, so I manually set my MONGOHQ_URL. Your uri would look something like:

```
mongodb://<user>:<password>@<the.db.host.com>:<port>/<database_name>
```

Looks to me like you can't connect to "localhost" based on the error (like maybe you need the full host name or IP or something?). Anything in your app logs?

**Just make sure not to set "host" and "uri" on any of the ENV's because "host" will override the setting that is derived from the uri.**

Comment: That did it- thank you so much!  I was about to pull my hair out! :)